# how would I keep my button from moving whenever I press it and change the margin

Tags: javascript

I am trying to keep my button from moving to the right whenever I press the button and change the margin of the page I am on. I am doing this to kinda simulate window resizing.

Here is a code-snippet of the current code:

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute("id", "1st");
button.innerText = "BRANCH";
button.style.color = 'red';
button.style.position = 'absolute';

button.style.zIndex = 0;
button.style.width = '16%';
button.style.height = '10%';

button.style.left = '45%';
button.style.bottom = '30%';
button.style.right = '0%';
button.style.top = '29%';
button.style.padding = '2% 3%';

document.querySelector('body').append(button);

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log("button pressed")

  var x = document.createElement("P");
  x.innerText = "THIS IS A TEST";
  x.style.marginLeft = "100%";
  x.style.zIndex = -1;

  document.querySelector('div').appendChild(x);

});
```

Comment: Try to share your html code also. You should avoid position in % because each time you resize window it changes position value

Comment: @raaahad this is purely a script for a google extension I am making for twitter so I am doing everything in js

Comment: oh! You should avoid position in % because each time you resize window it changes position value.

Comment: I have submitted an "edit" to the question. We are able to use stack-snippets to actually provide a quick demo within stackoverflow. When I re-size the window, the button retains it's position (ie, it does not move to the right). Do you need it to move right?

Comment: @jsN00b the code works on stack but for some reason when I inject it into twitter the same issue occurs

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue, button doesn't move.

Comment: @randominternetcoder what do you mean by injecting it into twitter? Twitter blocks HTML special chars.

Comment: @ethry its an unpacked extension that im using to inject to twitter

Answer (score 0):

### Cause of Problem here is `document.querySelector()`

#### According to developer.mozilla.org

The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned."

problem is when you use `document.querySelector('div')` it finds the "first" div in your code.

in here document.querySelector('div') might have found the div your button is also in.
Thus onclick 100% of margin left paragraph (`<p></p>`) tag is added to your document.